# I need to make an envelope to select points within but I get an error

Tags: postgis

I need to retrieve the records of which their coords are within a bounding box.

this SQL is giving me an error:

```
SELECT stores.id AS stores_id, stores.name_ar AS stores_name_ar, stores.name_en AS stores_name_en, ST_AsEWKB(stores.coordinates) AS stores_coordinates, stores.selfdelivery AS stores_selfdelivery, stores.rank AS stores_rank, stores.disabled AS stores_disabled, stores.created_at AS stores_created_at, stores.updated_at AS stores_updated_at 
FROM stores 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Envelope(POINT(23.154910755932406 57.10674190028622), POINT(23.154910755932406 57.10674190028622), 4326), stores.coordinates)
```

the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction) function st_envelope(unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 3: WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Envelope('POINT(23.154910755932406 57.1...
                          ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: To make a [mcve], you need to include some data definition statements.  Show how to create the table with a minimal amount of content, so your problem is reproducible.  I'm guessing you don't need quite so many columns, for starters.

Answer (score 0):

[`ST_Envelope()`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) requires a single parameter (a geometry), but you are passing three (`POINT(23.154910755932406 57.10674190028622)`, `POINT(23.154910755932406 57.10674190028622)` and `4326`).

Answer (score 0):

Your points are same in the example code. I guess you have two points like left-top corner and right-bottom corner points.

updated code below.

```sql
SELECT 
    stores.id AS stores_id, stores.name_ar AS stores_name_ar, stores.name_en AS stores_name_en, 
    ST_AsEWKB(stores.coordinates) AS stores_coordinates, stores.selfdelivery AS stores_selfdelivery, 
    stores.rank AS stores_rank, stores.disabled AS stores_disabled, 
    stores.created_at AS stores_created_at, stores.updated_at AS stores_updated_at 
FROM stores 
WHERE 
    stores.coordinates &&
    ST_SetSRID(
        ST_MakeBox2D(
            ST_Point(23.154910755932406, 57.10674190028622),
            ST_Point(24.154910755932406, 58.10674190028622)  
        ),
        4326
    )
```